# How to collect different properties from state based on clicked accordion in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parameters

How to collect "title" and "subtitle" from my menu array and pass it to onSelect function to render that title and subtitle in fullPage screen based on those params? I made an accordion with different props. I want to navigate from each accordion to fullPage screen which will render different title and subtitle based on accordion I clicked on. Any idea? Thanks in advance

```
export default class AccidentScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {`super(props);
        this.state = {`menu: [
                {
                    title: 'title1', icon: 'fire', color: 
 Colors.customRed,
                    data: [
                        {id: '1', subtitle: 'subtitle1' , subIcon: 'fire', 
 status: 'inactive'},
                ]
            },
            {
                title: 'title2', icon: 'street-view', color: 
    Colors.customLightBlue,
                data: [
                    {id: '2', subtitle: 'subtitle2' , subIcon: 'google- 
 wallet', status: 'inactive' },
                ]
            },
            {
                    title: 'title3', icon: 'water', color: 
Colors.customBrown,
                    data: [
                        {id: '3', subtitle: 'subtitle3', subIcon: 'earth', 
status: 'inactive'},
                        {id: '4', subtitle: 'subtitle4', subIcon: 'earth', 
status: 'inactive'},
                ]
            },
            {
                    title: 'title4', icon: 'fire', color: 
Colors.customGrey,
                    data: [
                        {id: '5', subtitle: 'subtitle5', subIcon: 'wind', 
status: 'inactive' },
                        {id: '6', subtitle: 'subtitle6' , subIcon: 'wind', 
status: 'inactive'},
                ]
            },
            {
                    title: 'title5', icon: 'car-crash', color: 
Colors.customRed,
                    data: [
                        {id: '7', subtitle: 'subtitle7',subIcon: 'car', 
status: 'inactive'},
                    {id: '8', subtitle: 'subtitle8', subIcon: 'car', 
status: 
'inactive'},
                ]
            },
        ]`
        
    }
}

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView>
                    {this.renderAccordians()}
                    <UrgentCall/>
                </ScrollView>
           
            </View>
        );
    }

    renderAccordians = () => {
        const items = [];

        for (item of this.state.menu){
           items.push (
               <Accordian
                 subtitle={item.subtitle}
                 title={item.title}
                 data={item.data}
                  menu={item.icon}
                  color={item.color}
                  onSelect={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate({routeName: 'FullPage', 
params: {accidentState: item} });
                }} />
             );
        }
        return items;`
    
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the code like that

```
export default class AccidentScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menu: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          {this.state.menu.map(item => (
            <Accordian
              subtitle={item.subtitle}
              title={item.title}
              data={item.data}
              menu={item.icon}
              color={item.color}
              onSelect={() => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate({
                  routeName: 'FullPage',
                  params: {accidentState: item},
                });
              }}
            />
          ))}
          <UrgentCall />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Or like that

```
class Accordian extends Component {
  render() {
    // Accordian component hold item props and pass down to parent component
    return <Button onPress={() => this.props.onSelect(this.props.item)} />;
  }
}

export default class AccidentScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      menu: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          {this.state.menu.map(item => (
            <Accordian
              item={item}
              onSelect={itemProps => {
                this.props.navigation.navigate({
                  routeName: 'FullPage',
                  params: {accidentState: itemProps},
                });
              }}
            />
          ))}
          <UrgentCall />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much :-) Your first solution is working but it always collects just first subtitle. When I click on the second subtitle of specific accordion it renders me always the first subtitle in my "FullPage" screen.

Comment: you can try the second one

Answer (score 0):

You have already helped me a lot. How could my 'Full Page Screen' know which subtitle in accordion I clicked on to pass that subtitle to 'Full Page' screen based on your first solution because the second one doesn't work.

My 'Full Page' screen component:

```
render() {

 const accident = this.props.navigation.getParam('accidentCat');

return (
<ScrollView>
   <View>
     <View>
       <Text>{accident.title}</Text>
       <Text>{accident.data[0].subtitle}</Text>
     </View>
   </View>
</ScrollView>
```

)
}